# Curve Fitting a Cyclical Pattern of Data

Tags: statistics, polynomials, graphing-functions, signal-processing, statistical-inference

I'm analyzing phonological characteristics of the 22 letters used in the Hebrew alphabet, and assigned each letter an enumeration to see if they are organized based on place of articulation:

- guttural = 1
- labial = 2
- palatal = 3
- coronal = 4

The following is the result (alphabetic order matched with articulation code):

```
1,1
2,2
3,3
4,4
5,1
6,2
7,4
8,1
9,4
10,3
11,3
12,4
13,2
14,4
15,4
16,1
17,2
18,4
19,3
20,4
21,4
22,4
```

When evaluating the differences between the articulation points of each successive letter (simple subtraction), it becomes subjectively apparent that there is a non-random cyclical pattern (oddly like a wave) whereby the increments subtracted from decrements balance out to equal 3.

Here's the table for the "step direction" (whereby a 1 -> 4 step above is a positive number here, and a 4 -> 1 step above would be a negative number here):

```
1,0
2,1
3,1
4,1
5,-3
6,1
7,2
8,-3
9,3
10,-1
11,0
12,1
13,-2
14,2
15,0
16,-3
17,1
18,2
19,-1
20,1
21,0
22,0
```

**Bottom Line:** Please help me understand how to characterize this pattern, how to fit it to the most relevant function model, and how to test it (given a sample size of 22) for confidence.

Here's a screenshot of what the graphs look like (red line shows the second table, and the area chart shows the first table).

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The numbers go up and down because they are bounded between $1$ and $4$, so they can't keep going up or going down forever. The total change (increments minus decrements) is $3$ simply because the sequence starts at $1$ and ends at $4$, that is, $4-1=3$. As such, I don't see any evidence of cyclical patterns in your data.

Comment: They can stay the same (0 change) at any time, but instead, the pattern is "1->4 (reset) 1->4 (reset), etc...". That means the letters are following a repeating phonological model. I need help in the questions at the bottom of the post to know how to take it from here.

Comment: See recently-added graphs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually do not believe Fourier analysis is relevant here.  You can't get reasonable likelihood measures in that direction.

Your data is discrete and your probabilities can be calculated directly.  What you are really looking at (as hinted by Rahul in the comments) is the combinatorics of rise and runs in a bounded sequence.  To measure how "atypical" this sequence is, you will want to look at the combinatorial properties.

First, you will want to understand the constraints you need to place.  You have a string of 22 numbers, each from 1 to 4.  You have at least one occurrence of each number (otherwise it wouldn't be a category that you would have classified the speech characteristics under), which gives a fairly large but manageable space to work with.  However, you probably want to start with the more narrow space of explicitly specifying that there are:

4 ones

4 twos

4 threes

10 fours

This is because you are analyzing the arrangements of an existing language with existing speech characteristics, not finding out how unusual the particular choice of language is in itself.  In other words, you just want to see if they arranged the alphabet in a way that is "meaningful" or has information content due to the layout, but the letters already exist and the layout is the only thing being checked.

This narrows the possible ways to arrange the phonological classification to $\binom{24}{10,4,4,4}$ or 12368268712800.

Now your data has 7 runs of rises and 6 runs of falls.  Is this typical of those 12,368,268,712,800 arrangements?  Or does it indicate this was not likely random?  You can calculate that!

L. Carlitz has a classical set of papers on this enumeration problem, starting with "Enumeration of sequences by rises and falls: a refinement of the Simon Newcomb problem".  Goulden and Jackson also cover this problem in "Combinatorial Enumeration".

You want to calculate the possibilities for all of the different possible rise/fall combinations and then you can understand how special or typical this particular case is.  The p-value can be calculated in the standard way by using the distribution given by probability over the rise/fall space.

I suspect what you will find is that seeing a number of rise and falls between 5 and 9 is pretty likely.  When you have 10 fours placed randomly, any gaps around them will be rise and falls.  Only the very rare cases where fours are bunched will not have a sinusoidal appearance.  But the details of the rise and fall enumeration with a specified set of characters in the string is rather involved, so I don't have numbers.  This may also be approachable by brute force enumeration or Monte-Carlo if the possibility space is too large.

Comment: For clarity, aside from randomness, can you suggest a function model that would approximate the red (wave-like) line graph, above?

Comment: @Yaaqov: I guess my point was that it is improper to function fit and expect any statistics here.  You do not have proper constraints to test any hypothesis using functional analysis here.  The set will never grow, and taking subsets significantly alters the statistics and behavior, so there is no good approach that direction.  So, if you want a model that allows you to identify information content, patterns, etc. and test any hypothesis related to periodicity of phonology in alphabet order, you have to use a combinatorial model.  I can fit a function perfectly here but it's not useful.

Comment: I'm not hypothesis testing, just describing the phenomenon algorithmically/mathematically in order to compare it with other ancient writing systems' attempts to organize all the sounds available in their languages. Do you mind linking to examples of the models you've referred to? I'm not familiar with them. Thanks in advance, and that should be enough for a final answer.

Comment: @Yaaqov: Okay.  You will want to remove the tags "statistics", "signal-processing", and particularly "statistical-inference" from your question.  You will also want to edit your question so it doesn't ask for the "most relevant" model or "how to test it for confidence".  It appears I have wasted time trying to answer a question you typed but didn't actually intend to ask.

Comment: You didn't waste time, it clarified where I need to go next, and it's far more helpful to discern this within two days than two months. Given your responses, I want to know the next step to characterizing this pattern mathematically, that's all. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

I would try [Fourier Analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_analysis) or a [Fast Fourier Transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_analysis#Discrete-time_Fourier_transform_.28DTFT.29). These will decompose your cyclic functions int a series of weighted sine functions. You can then choose the level of accuracy by truncating the number of sines you include in the series. As far as inferential confidence, you only have 22 samples, so you will likely need to get more data and see how well your fitted curve explains a *new* set of measurements. Absent that, you should try [cross validation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-validation_%28statistics%29), where you re-fit your fourier series model after leaving out 1 or more samples, then you rotate through all such combinatiosn to see the varability of your sine wave weights.

Comment: Do you have a formula in mind that approximates the red line-graph? Is this perhaps polynomial?

Comment: If not, perhaps you suggest a tool (preferably FOSS) that can help me experiment with curve fitting? I'm using spreadsheets at this early stage of research, limited to linear and exponential fitting.